# RF Engineering - Cascading a 3 Port S-Parameter Network into a 4-Port S-Parameter network

Tags: electrical-engineering, mathematics

I have been trying to cascade a 3-port scattering parameter network into a 4-port scattering parameter network that will ultimately be terminated by another 3-port network (as can be seen below).

[image]

The ports are not all terminated to a common impedance (for reasons pertinent to the work being done). For the sake of the mathematics, the SnP matrices are fully populated with non-zero values (i.e. there are loops caused by the cascade).

I have been able to find a lot of material online about how to cascade 2-port networks together but nothing on cascading non-2-port s-parameter networks.

Could someone possibly explain the general mathematical process for cascading these s-parameter networks into one another as described in the diagram?